# realtime Database in firebase doesn't save data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

realtime Database in firebase doesn't save data  and doesn't show any errors
i have already set

```
"rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
```

and this is the function it create new user and it's created in firebase but the user name and email doesn't save in realtime database
[image]

```
 public void createUser(String email, String password, String userName) {
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "user created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                User user = new User(email, userName);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "user info added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and this line is appere as toast i don't know how it is happen

```
   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "user info added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: The `onComplete` for a `setValue` only appears once the value has been written to disk on the server. So if your `user info added`, the write operation has completed. A typical first troubleshooting test I'd do is to simply do `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Test").setValue(true);` and see if that value shows up.

Comment: So are any of the onComplete methods triggered?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i tried it now but doesn't save it either

Comment: @AlexMamo no there is not